# How to trigger the Ringer Mode Change Event in Xamarin Android

Tags: c#, xamarin.android

> Hello Every One !!! I need to trigger the Ringer Mode Change Event i.e When user change the ringer mode , it directly detected , and talk the selected ringer mode that either user select the Vibrate , Silent Or Normal ringer mode.so in xamarin android native how it is possible ????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to register a `BroadcastReceiver`to trigger your event.
For example, the receiver:

```
    public class RingerBroadcastReceiver : BroadcastReceiver
    {
        public RingerBroadcastReceiver()
        {
        }

        public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
        {
            //Call your event
        }
    }
```

And use the following code to register in the `OnCreate()` method of the `MainActivity`:

```
        RingerBroadcastReceiver receiver = new RingerBroadcastReceiver();
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(
                        AudioManager.RingerModeChangedAction);
        RegisterReceiver(receiver, filter);
```